# Core Service API failed to connect to CMS from Linux box

Tags: 2013-sp1, core-service

I am trying to connect to CMS implementing Core Service API from my JAVA application. I have used below configuration to access the CMS -

```
    Address: http://ServerName.****.*****.com/webservices/CoreService2013.svc/basicHttp
    Encoding: UTF-8
    Http-Method: POST
    Content-Type: text/xml
    Headers: {Accept=[*/*], Authorization=[Basic Z2lsLmZlcm5hbmRlczpTYXJvdmFyMTYxMDghISE=], SOAPAction=["http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2013/ICoreService/GetApplicationIds"]}
    Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><GetApplicationIds xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2013" xmlns:ns2="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/R6" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:ns4="http://www.sdltridion.com/Security" xmlns:ns5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Now using this config my code is running properly from Windows machine. But when I am deploying my application in Linux box and trying to access the CMS, it is giving below error -

```
    2015-11-19 15:09:11,989 WARN  PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2013}ICoreServiceService#{http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2013}GetApplicationIds has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64) ~[cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514) [cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423) [cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:324) [cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:277) [cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96) [cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:139) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.getApplicationIds(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at com.jio.epc.integration.Main.main(Main.java:22) [epc-main-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '401: Unauthorized' when communicating with http://Servername.***.com/webservices/CoreService2013.svc/basicHttp
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1577) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1532) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1330) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56) ~[cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:215) ~[cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56) ~[cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:652) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62) ~[cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        ... 9 common frames omitted
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:150)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.getApplicationIds(Unknown Source)
        at com.jio.epc.integration.Main.main(Main.java:22)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '401: Unauthorized' when communicating with http://ServerName.***.com/webservices/CoreService2013.svc/basicHttp
```

Please Suggest.

Comment: Yes Pankaj! I have found the issue. Now from windows it is picking the right domain name but when i am trying to connect it from linux it is showing the wrong domain name.

Comment: OK, thanks for update - I have moved my comment as an answer and you want to accept it as an answer if it makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message itself suggest - '401: Unauthorized' which means the user you are using is not getting authorized.
Verify that you are passing the right credentials from the client to authenticate the Core Service client.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you tried this already, but have you seen my blog posts about connecting to Core Service from Java?

- http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/12/a-core-service-java-client.html
- http://yatb.mitza.net/2013/04/streamlining-core-service-java-client.html

Source code available at:

- https://github.com/mitza13/yet-another-tridion-blog/tree/master/Core%20Service%20Java%20Client
- https://github.com/mitza13/yet-another-tridion-blog/tree/master/Core%20Service%20Java%20Client/src/mitza/coreservice/client

Check out the CoreServiceFactory.java and Test.java